Token Literal Expected Error in Power Query M Code using try and List.MatchesAny
I'm working on a Power Query M script to rename columns in a table based on certain conditions. However, I'm encountering a "Token Literal Expected" error when trying to use the try expression within a List.MatchesAny function. Here’s the relevant portion of my code:
RenameColumnsFunction = (table as table) as table => 

let ColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(table),

//Apply transformation logic to each column name
RenamedColumns = List.Transform(ColumnNames, (colName) =>

// If any column values have a length of 4 and are numeric, rename the column to "Org level 2 Code"


    if 
        List.MatchesAny(Table.Column(table, colName), each try 
        Text.Length(Text.From(_)) = 4 and **try **
        Number.FromText(Text.From(_)) <> null otherwise false) 
        then
        {colName, "Org Level 2 Code"} 

// If the column name matches one of the predefined names, rename it to "Headcount Label"
        
        else if 

        List.Contains({"ACCTG", "ADMIN", "ASM", "AWE", "CFO", "CROCOL", "CUSTSRV", "DEV", "ENGIN","FIN","FLDSP", "HOM", "HR","IT", "MERCH", "PROSVC"}, colName) 
        
        then
        {colName, "Headcount Label"} 
        
        else {colName, colName}  // Keep the original name if no match 
        
        ),
        RenamedTable = Table.RenameColumns(table, RenamedColumns, MissingField.Ignore) 
        
        in RenamedTable, 

// Step 4: Apply the renaming function to each table query
ApplyRename = Table.AddColumn(FilteredQueries, "Transformed Data", each RenameColumnsFunction([Content])), 

// Step 5: Expand the renamed tables (ensure there's data to extract) 
RenamedTables = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ApplyRename, "Transformed Data", Table.ColumnNames(ApplyRename[Content]{0})),

// Step 6: Combine all queries into one table if needed 
CombinedData = Table.Combine(RenamedTables[TransformedData]) 
in 

CombinedData


Function to rename columns in a table
//function fRename
(xtable as table) as table => 
let names=Table.ColumnNames(xtable),
z = List.Transform(names, each
    let a=_, 
    b= Value.Is(Value.FromText(a), type number) in
    if Text.Length(a)=4 and b then "Org Level 2 Code" else 
    if List.Contains({"ACCTG", "ADMIN", "ASM", "AWE", "CFO", "CROCOL", "CUSTSRV", "DEV", "ENGIN","FIN","FLDSP", "HOM", "HR","IT", "MERCH", "PROSVC"}, a) then "Headcount Label" 
    else a  
 ),
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns(xtable,List.Zip({names,z}))
in #"Rename"

And to use it
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Process"=fRename(Source)
in #"Process"

